# Table in Python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

Here its printing sunday in all the cells in the table

```
docu = docx.Document()

daylist = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
           "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

num_of_days = int(input('enter days'))
num_of_lectures = int(input('lecture number'))

timetable = docu.add_table(rows=num_of_days, cols=num_of_lectures)
tablecell = timetable.cell(0, 1)
tablerow = timetable.rows[1]

for day in daylist:
    for tablerow in timetable.rows:
        for tablecell in tablerow.cells:
            tablecell.text = day

docu.save('timetable.docx')
```

and if I'm doing this it's printing the whole list in each cell.

```
docu = docx.Document()

daylist = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
           "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

num_of_days = int(input('enter days'))
num_of_lectures = int(input('lecture number'))

timetable = docu.add_table(rows=num_of_days, cols=num_of_lectures)
tablecell = timetable.cell(0, 1)
tablerow = timetable.rows[1]

for tablerow in timetable.rows:
    for tablecell in tablerow.cells:
        tablecell.text = (day for day in daylist)

docu.save('timetable.docx')
```

and I've tried

```
daylist = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday",
           "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"]

num_of_days = int(input('enter days'))
num_of_lectures = int(input('lecture number'))

timetable = docu.add_table(rows=num_of_days, cols=num_of_lectures)
tablerow = timetable.rows[1]

i = 0
for cells in timetable.rows:
    i += 1
    tablecell = timetable.cell(i, 0)
    cells.text = (day for day in daylist)

docu.save('timetables.docx')
```

I need one string from `daylist` list in only top row. Python docx documentation is difficult to understand.

Comment: I think I may see the problem now. What do you think `(day for day in daylist)` will return?

Comment: string from ```daylist ``` one by one?

Comment: `(day for day in daylist)` is a generator expression, which yields values from `daylist`. I think I focused on the wrong thing, I should have asked what `tablecell.text = (day for day in daylist)` does.

Comment: I assumed ```tablecell``` will be the first cell in the table and it keeps iterating in the first row because of  ```timetable.rows[1]``` (which is wrong) and with that iterating with strings from daylist at the same time. I thought I'd get the desired output.

Comment: Do you understand how it works now?

Comment: Yes, cells were iterating but ```day for day in daylist``` was iterating  completely and printing all strings for each iterated cell. Right?

Comment: Yup! Good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python code is faithfully doing what you are asking it to do. Perhaps you are confused about how iteration works.

I'm assuming you want a result that looks like this:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
| Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|        |         |           |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|        |         |           |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

This can be accomplished a variety of ways, but something like this would do the trick:

```
cells = table.rows[0].cells
for i in num_of_days:
   cells[i].text = daylist[i]
```

or perhaps better:

```
for i, cell in enumerate(table.rows[0].cells):
    cell.text = daylist[i]
```

slightly fancier would be:

```
for cell, title in zip(table.rows[0].cells, daylist):
    cell.text = title
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still trying to understand how concepts in docx work. I'm not able to understand meaning of few methods and how they link together.

Comment: Keep working at it, it will come to you sooner than you think! :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import itertools

tablerow = timetable.rows[0]

for (day, cell) in zip(itertools.cycle(daylist), tablerow):
    cell.text = day
```

Comment: add context to prevent down-voting and/or bot removal of answer.